# Function Problem

Tags: equation-solving, functions, functional-style

[image: Function Problem]

Hello, I was wondering how to solve this problem using Mathematica?

Comment: I tried using Solve but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = 2 x + 3;
```

g[x] is `g[x+2] /. x -> x-2`

```
g[x_] = f[f[x - 1]*f[x + 1] + f[x]] /. x -> x - 2 // Simplify

(*  -5 - 4 x + 8 x^2  *)
```

For the specific case

```
g[6]

(*  259  *)
```

**EDIT:** Verifying,

```
g[x + 2] == f[f[x - 1]*f[x + 1] + f[x]] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complicated functional dependence of g like

```
   g[func] == f[f[x - 1]*f[x + 1] + f[x]]
```

substitute y and Solve for x:

```
   h[y_, func_] := f[f[x - 1]*f[x + 1] + f[x]] /. Solve[y == func, x] // Simplify
```

and get

```
    h[6, x + 2]

    (*   {259}    *)

    h[6, x^2 + 2 x]

    (*   {55 - 12 Sqrt[7], 55 + 12 Sqrt[7]}   *)

    h[4 y - 5, x + 2]

    (*   {215 - 336 y + 128 y^2}   *)
```